# html hyperlink not working

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

I have an image link that, when clicked, does not link to the proper link. It will find a local file instead with that name and therefor show that the page doesnt exist. Im doing this on Visual Studio 2012.

My code is

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="images/box3.png"/></a>
```

but when i run it the link says localhost/google.com so it doesnt work.

I've tried doing ../../ or ../ and that doesn't work either. Does any one know why? I've googled it but can't find an answer. I dont understand why it doesnt just work.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is not displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the protocol in your URL. Without it the URL is *relative* to the current URL which is not what you want.

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="images/box3.png"/></a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/box3.png"/></a>
```